# Server Error in '/' Application. on asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Getting this error when working on nopcommerce theme

```
[A]System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection cannot be cast to
```

`[B]System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection. Type A originates from`
 `'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,` 
`PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' in the context 'Default' at location 'C:\Windows`

```
\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.WebPages.Razor\v4.0_2.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35


\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll'. Type B originates from 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, 

Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' in the context 

'Default' at location 'C:\Users\Designer_2\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root

\c152d41b\a654685e\assembly\dl3\d2c346c5\cbf4b46b_e2d3ce01\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll'.
```

Please advise how to solve?

Comment: Can you please provide the code where you're performing the cast?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure in the `web.config` in your application root and `Views` folder are referencing the same version of Razor that you're referencing in your project, similar to below:

```
<sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
</sectionGroup>
```